# Creating read-only file with TASM Assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I have to write a TASM program in which a read-only file is created. I created the file but it is not read-only. What's wrong? Here's the code:

```
model small
.data
    handle dw 0
    filename db "file2.txt",0
.stack 256
.code
main:

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,3ch 
    mov cx,1         
    lea dx,filename 
    int 21h 
    jc exit

    mov handle,ax
exit:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
end main
```

Edit: I changed `mov cx,1` to `mov cx,01h` and it worked.

P.S: I also want the file to be hidden so 
once again I changed to `mov cx,03h` and done. The created file is read-only and hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bit 7 = 1: Shareable
Bit 6 = 1: Archive
Bit 5 = 1: Directory
Bit 4 = 1: Volume (ignored)
Bit 3 = 1: Label
Bit 2 = 1: System
Bit 1 = 1: Hidden
Bit 0 = 1: Read-only
```

Edit:
My original answer was incorrect as the values I stated were bitwise, so for clarity decimal would be:

```
mov cx, 0       ;  No attributes. 
mov cx, 1       ;  Read-only. 
mov cx, 2       ;  Hidden. 
mov cx, 4       ;  System 
mov cx, 16      ;  Archive
```

For multiple attributes add the values together.

This means the value of CX was correct in your original post as 1 is 1 whether in decimal or hex (or binary), so whatever changes you made, that should not be what solved it.

Glad you got it working though.

Comment: You are right.I was trying to write this on 64bit windows 8 using DOSBox and it was not working completely.So I wrote the same code on my older windows XP PC(with no DOSBox) and this time it was working.

Comment: It's more typical to OR values together when they represent bits in a bitfield.  e.g. `1 | 2` rather than `1 + 2`

Comment: In code, yes, but for the purposes of this the result is the same. The user will not be doing any bitwise calculations on it.

Comment: @JBES: I meant in the asm source, of course not at runtime.  Like `mov  cx, 1 | 2`, or `mov cx, O_RDONLY | O_HIDDEN` or something.

Comment: In the above either will work so I repeat - No bitwise calculations will be done with the value required so it is wholly unnecessary in this case as it is hard coded.